# Is there a formula for the square root of the following matrix?

Tags: probability, matrix-decomposition

I'm given a probability distribution vector $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ - $p^T \mathbf{1} = 1$ and $p_i \ge 0$.
Given the matrix 
$$H = \mathbf{diag}(p) - p p^T$$
Is there any fast/easy way of calculating its square root without having to do full Cholesky decomposition?

Note that the matrix itself is PSD with the vector $\mathbf{1}$ being the eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial to compute the Cholesky factorization of $\mbox{diag}(p)$.  Subtracting $pp^{T}$ is a rank-one update (sometimes called a "downdate" because of the subtraction), and methods based on the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula can be used to compute the updated Cholesky factorization easily.

See the Wikipedia page on the [Cholesky factorization and particularly the section on rank one downdating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Rank-one_downdate).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, however, the procedure does not seem to work, and my guess is because the matrix becomes singular.

Comment: A quick and dirty approach is to subtract 0.999999pp' rather than pp'.  Note that MATLAB has a built-in cholupdate function that you can use.

Comment: Ah, that was stupid not to think of it... I guess it was quite late here. Thanks for the help, just a last question - is there a FORTRAN routine for this, which I can use out of matlab?

Comment: I don't know of any available Fortran code, but it's not too hard to implement.

Comment: Is there a possible connection with the interpretation of (n times) $diag(p-pp^t)$ as the variance matrix of a multinomial distribution with distribution vector $p$ ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)